# How do I get mrbs installed and working?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I'm trying to install [Meeting Room Booking System](http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/download.php) on ubuntu 12.04
I think I have apache and php5 up and working fine. A test.php file with contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

loads and gives me plenty of info.

Here's the guide I attempted to follow

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/doityourself-it-guy/diy-install-and-configure-meeting-room-booking-system/678

Unfortunately I point my browser at localhost/mrbs/web/
and I get a blank document.

Any ideas?

Comment: jorge: did you edit to only remove the 12.04 tag? Did I use it inappropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what I want is called a LAMP server.
According to the [Here](http://ubuntudan.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/installing-lamp-on-ubuntu-1204-precise.html) all I need to do is

```
 sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

with the ^ or else it doesn't work. Anyhow I've done this and I no longer get a blank page now I get a "Fatal error: failed to connect to database"

Turns out, I had tried to give my mrbs mysql user enough privileges, but it didn't go right. Fixed this and it works!